# Ignoring non-english words from getting indexed

Tags: marklogic

I have an xml with a text element, which holds text read from an OCR. The OCR read text is not always accurate therefore there are instances where misspelled english words appear. Is there a way that I could specify that only words in the english dictionary be indexed.

Comment: For what purpose would you want to ignore them?

Comment: I do not want them to be indexed, as the index gets bloated with too many words not in the english dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

With MarkLogic, the database configuration and the XML make up the indexing API. So this sort of customization will often involve changes to the XML. Here I see two basic approaches:

1. Transform the text to strip out words that are not in your dictionary. They will not appear in the XML, so they will not be indexed.
2. Transform the text to mark up words that are not in your dictionary, then configure the database word query settings to exclude that element. They will still appear in the XML, but MarkLogic will not create word query terms for the excluded element.

Ideally either of these transforms would be done by the OCR software, but you could implement either as part of a custom CPF pipeline.

Another approach to consider is to check user queries for non-English words, and exclude those. That might take the form of a "did you mean?" prompt.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. There is no control over the OCR output. Option 2 would be the better approach as we do not want to strip out data.

Comment: A full example of a CPF pipeline would be a little long for SO, but try getting started with https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf/quickStart and open up new questions as needed. At some point you'll have to write a transform in XQuery or XSLT, and work with a spelling dictionary.